# How to connect android apps to wearable apps?

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-notification

I am currently working on Android Wearable application but i am quite beginner to wearable application, i have one small doubt which i need to rectify.

So i have one screen with button on my mobile apps, so if i press the button then i want the background color should change on wear.

**Mobile App**

```
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       //How to send request to Wear Apps
    }
});
```

**Wear App**

```
final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
    stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
            //How to receive request from Android mobile app
        }
    });
```

[image]

And please go though the screenshot and check my project heir-achy and suggest me some solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**From mobile side** inside you activity/fragment, create a connection

```
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getContext())
            .addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                @Override
                public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "API client connected");
                }

                @Override
                public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "API client connection suspended");
                }
            })
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "API client connection failed");
                }
            })
            .addApi(Wearable.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

Use DataMap to send data items

```
    PutDataMapRequest putDataMapRequest = PutDataMapRequest.create("/app");
    putDataMapRequest.getDataMap().putString("DATA", data); // your data
    PutDataRequest putDataRequest = putDataMapRequest.asPutDataRequest();
    PendingResult<DataApi.DataItemResult> pendingResult = Wearable.DataApi.putDataItem(mGoogleApiClient, putDataRequest);
    pendingResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DataApi.DataItemResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(DataApi.DataItemResult dataItemResult) {
            if (dataItemResult.getStatus().isSuccess()){
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Sent weather data to watch");
            }
            else{
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Unable to send data to watch");
            }
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    });
```

Dependencies

```
compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:1.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:7.8.0'
```

**From Wear side**, receive data in activity

```
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getBaseContext())
                .addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "API client connected");
                        final DataApi.DataListener dataListener = new DataApi.DataListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEventBuffer) {
                                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "onDataChanged(): " + dataEventBuffer);
                                for (DataEvent event: dataEventBuffer){
                                    if (event.getType() == DataEvent.TYPE_CHANGED){
                                        DataItem dataItem = event.getDataItem();
                                        if (dataItem.getUri().getPath().equals("/app")){
                                            DataMap dataMap = DataMapItem.fromDataItem(dataItem).getDataMap();
                                            String data = dataMap.getString("DATA"); // You have received the data, do your stuff
                                            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "data " + data);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        };
                        Wearable.DataApi.addListener(mGoogleApiClient, dataListener);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "API client connection suspended");
                    }
                })
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "API client connection failed");
                    }
                })
                .addApi(Wearable.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

Dependencies

```
compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:1.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:7.8.0'
```

Comment: hey on wear it's always going to the "API client connection failed"

Comment: Make sure you are using same version of play services on mobile and wear. Also check in logcat if any warning related to play services version is coming or not!

Comment: yes both are same version of google play but after it's connect to Google play it's not coming inside onDataChanged.